# Erlang: Why can't I link two gen_servers?

Tags: erlang, spawn, gen-server

I have two gen_server modules. 
First **serv.erl**

```
-module(serv).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([init/1, 
     handle_call/3,
     handle_cast/2, 
     handle_info/2,
     code_change/3,
     terminate/2,
     start_link/0
    ]).
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    spawn_link(user, start_link,[]),
    {ok, []}.

handle_call(_E, _From, State) ->
        {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(_Message, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

handle_info(Message, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

code_change(_OldVersion, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

And **user.erl** (which is completely the same except init/1):

```
init([]) ->
     {ok, []}.
```

I thought that the servers would last forever. And if the first server dies another one gets *{'EXIT', Pid, Reason}* message.

But if you start the modules by **serv:start_link()** , the **user** module will exit immediately after the start with a message *{'EXIT',Pid,normal}* .
Why does **user** die?

Comment: insted of this spawn_link(user, start_link,[]) try user:start_link().

Comment: Sidenote: Don't name your module ever `user`. Erlang already comes with a module that is named like this, and you will either not see your own module or prevent the EVM from booting because the expected `user` module does not behave as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the spawn link function, you are starting a new process which calls `user:start_link`.  That process starts and links to a user gen_server process, and then exits, since the call to `user:start_link` returned.  The user process is linked to that process, so it gets an exit signal.  Since the user process isn't trapping exits, it also exits.

You should just run `user:start_link` in your `serv:init` function, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

`spawn` and `spawn_link` are the two basic Erlang functions for starting a new process. Both will create a process which then calls the function with arguments as specified in the arguments to `spawn`/`spawn_link`. **When that function ends the process automatically terminates with the exit reason `normal`.** The difference between the functions is that `spawn_link` also creates a *link* between the two processes.

The `gen_server:start_link` function does much more than just creating the process by initiating the behaviour and then running a behaviour top-loop which provides all the behaviour functionality. Amongst other things the callback function `init` is called to initialise the behaviour and then return `{ok,State}` to tell the behaviour that everything has been initialised and went well and here is the local state it is to pass into all the callbacks. The callback functions of a gen_server are not meant to be called directly but by the behaviour.

So when you explicitly spawn a process just running the `init` function it will terminate as soon as the `init` function ends. This is what happening here.

The `{'EXIT',Pid,Reason}` messages comes from the processes being linked and that the process is *trapping exits*. When a process dies an *exit signal* is sent from the dying process to all the processes to which it is linked. When this signal arrives at a process trapping exits then it is **converted** to normal message and put in that processes message queue. This is what you are seeing here. Note that all this is done **automatically** because of the link and trapping exits.

I hope that helps. Sorry for being a bit over-didactic here.